# can i revoke deviceToken?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I received 3 push notifications which had the same contents.
In the beginning I think i received duplicate push notifications.

But I found that this push notifications were sent by different deviceToken.

Maybe something wrong when I re-install app again and again by Xcode, so APNS didn't revoke the deviceToken successfully.

My server stored all deviceTokens and push notification by these deviceTokens and there are some deviceTokens in APNS will point to my iPhone, so I received many notifications.

If I am right, can I revoke other deviceToken?
Or it caused by other reason?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

// Register for Push Notitications, if running iOS 8
if ([application  respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes =    (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                       UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                       UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
  } else {
    // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
  }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{

//send deviceToken to server
NSLog(@"Token is: %@", deviceToken);
}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of the app with different bundle ids installed on your iphone?

Comment: may be server side your device token stored n number of times ?check it ..

Comment: Paradeep, no,i don't. 
Kishorem, ok, i will check it

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing app automatically revokes old token. So App with a unique bundle Id can't have multiple tokens at a time.

You may have issue on server side, which might be sending multiple push notifications to this token, or might be linking same token with multiple users.

Comment: but just me get multiple push notifications, this is confusing me

Comment: Issue is on your server side. Now question is, how to track your server algorithm for sending PUSH. Multiple tokens shouldn't have anything to do it, they get expired automatically. Check your server database, for your current device token, and with how many users it is linked to.